# WordPress on MAMP wants WebFTP for updates. Where can I find this?

Tags: wordpress, ftp, localhost, mamp

I've installed WordPress on my local machine with MAMP.
If I want to updates the system or plugins, WordPress asks for WebFTP credentials every time. I've tried root/root on localhost and localost:8888. Both are wrong?

Where can I find/set these credentials?
Or is there a way to prevent WP from asking?

The issue is new for me. In the past there was no need for WebFTP credentials?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've always told WordPress to edit files directly for updating WordPress instead of using FTP. To do that add `define('FS_METHOD', 'direct');` to your wp-config.php file and then make sure that the files are owned by the user that runs Apache. I think that by default the free version of MAMP runs as you so you shouldn't need to do anything different with file permissions.

Below is the documentation from WP's [Editing wp-config.php](https://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php) documentation page for `FS_METHOD` constant.

> **FS_METHOD** forces the filesystem method. It should only be "direct",
>   "ssh2", "ftpext", or "ftpsockets". Generally, you should only change
>   this if you are experiencing update problems. If you change it and it
>   doesn't help, change it back/remove it. Under most circumstances,
>   setting it to 'ftpsockets' will work if the automatically chosen
>   method does not. Note that your selection here has serious security
>   implications. If you are not familiar with them, you should seek help
>   before making a change.
>
> ```
> **(Primary Preference) "direct"** forces it to use Direct File I/O requests from within PHP. It is the option chosen by default.
> **(Secondary Preference) "ssh2"** is to force the usage of the SSH PHP Extension if installed
> **(3rd Preference) "ftpext"** is to force the usage of the FTP PHP Extension for FTP Access, and finally
> **(4th Preference) "ftpsockets"** utilises the PHP Sockets Class for FTP Access.
> ```